# Generic function parameter in Swift points to invalid memory

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'll start with an example setup.

```
class Parent {
    let parentProperty = 1
}
class Child : Parent {
    let childProperty = 2
}
class Test {
    func testMethod<T : Parent>(data: T) {
        // (llbd) print data
    }
}

let child = Child()
let test = Test()
// (lldb) print child
test.testMethod(child)
```

I paused execution on places marked with comment "(lldb) print ..." and executed "print child/data" command in debugger console in Xcode.

Output from said commands are listed below.

// print child

```
(RingRingTests.Child) $R0 = 0x00007fcb886459a0 {
  RingRingTests.Parent = {
    parentProperty = 1
  }
  childProperty = 2
}
```

// print data

```
(RingRingTests.Child) $R1 = 0x0000000115a93818 {
  RingRingTests.Parent = {
    parentProperty = 140512143366480
  }
  childProperty = 4294967299
}
```

The child and data variables obviously point to different location in memory. (being that data point to some invalid memory)

This seems to be like the most basic setup for generic function is swift, nevertheless it is failing.

I guess I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Can somebody point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Using `unsafeAddressOf`, `data` and `child` print the same memory address for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to replace your proposed lldb-tests with plain old debug output and all works fine.

```
class Parent: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    let parentProperty = 1
    var debugDescription: String { return "\(parentProperty)" }
}
class Child: Parent {
    let childProperty = 2
    override var debugDescription: String { return "\(parentProperty), \(childProperty)" }
}
class Test {
    func testMethod<T : Parent>(data: T) {
        print(data)
    }
}

let child = Child()
let test = Test()
print(child) // 1, 2
test.testMethod(child) // 1, 2
```

Some optimisation can screw lldb-tests, but optimisation should not be done for debug builds.

In other words, my answer is "it's actually all right with your code, but maybe something is wrong with your tests".

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to find en error in my program and got distracted by all the wrong debug information XCode was providing. It's a shame that logging to console is still the only way I can debug my code...

Comment: Try to use debugger on the modified code _with_ debug output. It may demonstrate correct results, because all the variables are _actually_ used and in no way can be optimised out preserving the program correctness.